# How to explore a PSITree in intellij API?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to build an Intellij plugin that identifies scala classes with certain annotations.

ex:

```
@RunWith(classOf[SimpleTestRunner])
```

When I build the PSITree using the PSIViewer pluging for the last code segment I get this Tree

```
ScalaFile:Dummy.scala(0,36)
  PsiErrorElement:Wrong top statement declaration(0,0)
    <empty list>
  PsiElement(@)('@')(0,1)
  MethodCall(1,35)
    ReferenceExpression: RunWith(1,8)
      PsiElement(identifier)('RunWith')(1,8)
    ArgumentList(8,35)
      PsiElement(()('(')(8,9)
      GenericCall(9,34)
        ReferenceExpression: classOf(9,16)
          PsiElement(identifier)('classOf')(9,16)
        TypeArgumentsList(16,34)
          PsiElement([)('[')(16,17)
          SimpleType: SimpleTestRunner(17,33)
            CodeReferenceElement: SimpleTestRunner(17,33)
              PsiElement(identifier)('SimpleTestRunner')(17,33)
          PsiElement(])(']')(33,34)
      PsiElement())(')')(34,35)
```

Now, I'm trying to access children with navigation element "ReferenceExpression,ArgumentList,GenericCall", I know how to visit tree recursively, but I don't know what to look for.

So can someone tell me what are the interfaces that represents these elements or is there sort of a utiltiy class that could help me to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have the [source code of the Scala plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala)?

The interfaces (or Scala traits actually) are defined in the org.jetbrains.plugins.scale.lang.psi.api package. There you can find [./expr/ScGenericCall.scala](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/idea172.x/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/lang/psi/api/expr/ScMethodCall.scala) for example. Every element in your tree has a corresponding Sc<NAME>.scala file where it is defined.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I'm using Java to develop this plugin and also I don't want to depend on Scala concrete implementation as this plugin should also work for java classes that have the same annotation, so I'm looking for the Java interfaces that are implemented by these classes in order to depend on the and my plugin works for java and scala

Comment: Sorry, but there are no Java interfaces implemented by these traits (except for PsiElement). Your plugin will have to have a dependency ([can be optional](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_configuration_file.html)) on the Scala plugin. I think it's possible to use the traits from Java, or you can choose to implement part of your plugin in Scala.